# Round() hacia abajo con 0.5 Oracle

Tags: redondeo, oracle-19c

Me encuentro trabajando con Oracle 19c, necesito realizar un redondeo hacia abajo cuando mi valor decimal sea menor o igual a .5 y hacia arriba cuando mi valor decimal sea mayor o igual a .6, el ROUND por si solo me realiza un redondeo hacia arriba a partir de .5,

En una consulta, la realice como `SELECT FLOOR(-2.54 * POWER(10,0)+0.4) * POWER(10,0) FROM DUAL;` y obtengo el resultado de -3, en cambio si coloco 2.54 (positivo) si obtengo el resultado esperado de 2

¿saben si existe alguna manera o posibilidad de lograr que su funcionamiento cambie, es decir que redondee hacia arriba pero a partir de .6? de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que esto es un poco independiente del tipo de BD en pseudocodigo `int( x + 0.4)` ajusta a tu caso y si es un orden de magnitud diferente para una cierta cantidad de decimales significativos puedes multiplicar por 10 a la n con n un orden de magnitud menos sumar 0.4 tomar parte entera y dividir por 10 a la n

Comment: Si eso funciona pero con valores positivos, con los negativos no:(

Comment: En una consulta o un bloque PLSQL?

Comment: En una consulta, la realice como SELECT FLOOR(-2.54 * POWER(10,0)+0.4) * POWER(10,0) FROM DUAL; y obtengo el resultado de -3, en cambio si coloco 2.54 (positivo)  si obtengo el resultado esperado de 2

Comment: pero estás diciendo que si es -x.yy, siendo yy <= .59, debe ser hacia abajo y en el caso de -2.54, la parte no entera es .54 que *es menor que .6* y eso va a dar -3 (que es el piso de ese número). No se entiende tu pregunta. Es como si quisieras obtener el valor *más cercano a cero* en lugar de un redondeo

Comment: No, no quiero obtener el valor más cercano al número entero, quiero que mientras sea igual o menor a .59 el redondeo sea hacia abajo y si es igual o mayor a .6 el redondeo sea hacia arriba, mi valor de -2.54 debería de dar -2, sin embargo me devuelve un -3

Comment: Pero es que -3 < -2, así que floor(-2.54) es -3. No va a dar -2 en esa lógica. Abajo es -3

Comment: Entonces como sugieres que realice el calculo?

Comment: No lo sé porque no sé qué buscas. Quieres simplemente redondeo hacia abajo para <.60 y para arriba si >=.60? Si es así, la consulta que ya tienes no funciona? Revisa nuevamente tus casos de prueba, no se trata de cómo hacer el cálculo sino de tus escenarios de prueba para el código que decidas implementar

Comment: Si quiero redondeo hacia abajo si es <=.59 y hacia arriba si es >=.60, la consulta funciona, creí que tenías otra opción

Answer (score 1):

Haz el round con el valor de entrada -.1 y así compensas.

```
round(valor - 0.1)
```

Si necesitas considerar negativos, esto podría servir

```
case
    when valor > 0 then round(valor - 0.1)
    else round(valor + 0.1)
end
```

o incluso

```
round(valor + case when valor > 0 then -0.1 else 0.1 end)
```

Que *creo* que debería funcionar

Comment: Pero cuando el valor es negativo lo que hace es sumarlo, no restarlo y ya no me devuelve el valor que espero.-.

Comment: Podrías ser un poco más explicito en tu propuesta, no comprendo la multiplicación por 0.4

Comment: Hola @AriagnaBandalaSalazar en la sugerencia para negativos **me equivoqué** y regresé a borrarla. Para redondear hacia abajo necesitas la parte entera. En el caso de los positivos es natural al habla, en el caso de los negativos no lo es porque la parte entera es el mayor entero menor que el número dado. ej de -1.5 es -2 y la de -0.3 es -1. Si necesitas "jugar con ese comportamiento" tienes que tener en cuenta que -0.4 > -0.5 en la misma relación que 0.6 > 0.5 de modo que el mismo redondeo que opera para 0.7 opera para -0.3 al sumar 0.4 y tomar parte entera 0.7 va a 1 y -0.3 va a 0 sigue...

Comment: ... continua @AriagnaBandalaSalazar De modo que el comportamiento que esperas los menores o iguales que (+-)n.5 bajan y los mayores suben se obtiene. De modo que mi primera sugerencia si funciona